# What is p1 and p2 in the power.prop.test in R and how to use them for power analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How to use the power.prop.test function in R if I want to find "n" for an experiment using 80% power
to see a decrease in metastasis level to 50% in the treated mice using significance level of 0.05

Comment: Does https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/power.prop.test.html help?